# setting sklearn MLPclassifier's activation parameter for multiple hidden layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, backpropagation

I have designed a neural network that has two hidden layers with different activation functions. How can I set the activation function for each layer different from the other layers using sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier library?

is there something similar to this?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier(alpha=1e-5 ,hidden_layer_sizes=(10,5),activation=['tanh','relu'])
```

the error was:
the error was:" raise ValueError("The activation '%s' is not supported)"

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work? If not, what was the error?

Comment: the error was:" raise ValueError("The activation '%s' is not supported)"

Comment: Such information should be part of the question, and *not* in the comments; please edit & update your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html), the activitation can be one of:

```
activation{‘identity’, ‘logistic’, ‘tanh’, ‘relu’}, default=’relu’

    Activation function for the hidden layer.

        ‘identity’, no-op activation, useful to implement linear bottleneck, returns f(x) = x

        ‘logistic’, the logistic sigmoid function, returns f(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x)).

        ‘tanh’, the hyperbolic tan function, returns f(x) = tanh(x).

        ‘relu’, the rectified linear unit function, returns f(x) = max(0, x)
```

There is no option to set different activations for different layers. And recall that a MLP is conceptually more simple than a full-fledged neural network. If you want a simple architecture, then why not just use the same activation for both layers? If you want more control, then switch to a real deep learning framework.

Comment: Thanks. I just reviewed sklearn library code and as you said that can't be implemented using MLPclassifer class.